# Seaborn heatmap confusion matrix display not displaying as expected

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

please guide me on the heat map display for confusion matrix .I have tried different fig size  but not getting proper display.My code below and the screen shot

[image: Confusion Matrix Seaborn]

```
def show_confusion_matrix(test_labels,predictions):
    confusion=sk_metrics.confusion_matrix(np.argmax(test_labels,axis=1),np.argmax(predictions,axis=1))
    confusion_normalized=confusion.astype('float')/confusion.sum(axis=1)
    #confusion_normalized=confusion_matrix(np.argmax(y_test,axis=1),np.argmax(predictions,axis=1))
    axis_labels=list(uniquelabel) ## unique labels has 120 dog breed names
    fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(30,70))
    ax=sns.heatmap(confusion_normalized,xticklabels=axis_labels,yticklabels=axis_labels,
                   linewidths=0.10,cmap='Blues',annot=True,fmt='.2f',square=True)
    plt.title('Confusion_matrix')
    plt.ylabel("True Label")
    plt.xlabel("Predicted Label")

show_confusion_matrix(y_test,predictions)
```

Comment: Screen-shot is not available.

Comment: Added now,please check in the description link thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem I spot is font-size

```
from seaborn import set
from seaborn import set_style

set(font_scale=1.8)
set_style("darkgrid")
```

or you can set style [whitegrid](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.set_style.html)

You have lots of features, therefore I suggest you apply mask for a simple approach.

```
from numpy import zeros_like
from numpy import triu_indices_from

mask = zeros_like(confusion_normalized)
mask[triu_indices_from(mask)] = True
```

You need to use `confusion_normalized` since you want to plot the normalized confusion matrix.

```
from seaborn import axes_style
from matplotlib.pyplot import subplots

with axes_style("white"):
    f, ax = subplots(figsize=(15, 15))
    ax = heatmap(confusion_normalized, 
                 annot=True, 
                 mask=mask, 
                 vmax=1,
                 vmin=0,
                 square=True, 
                 cmap="YlGnBu",
                 linewidths=1.5, 
                 annot_kws={"size": 18})
    
savefig('heatmap.png')
```

[An Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tUvL.png)

Comment: Thanks @Ahmet , didnt work as expected with below modificatons to code

Comment: Well I can't be 100% accurate since I don't have your data. What is the error?

Comment: Not error, but the display is very cramped and display is not like your output, i have around 120 features

Comment: I will suggest changing the following parameters; reduce `set(font_scale=1.8)` and `annot_kws={"size": 18})`, increase `f, ax = subplots(figsize=(15, 15))`.

Comment: Working now with following modifications
```
  axis_labels=list(uniquelabel)
  fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(50,50))
  ax=sns.heatmap(confusion_normalized, 
                 annot=True, 
                 xticklabels=axis_labels,
                 yticklabels=axis_labels,
                 mask=mask, 
                 square=True, 
                 cmap="YlGnBu",
                 linewidths=1.5, 
                 fmt='.2f',
                 annot_kws={"size":12}
                 )
 
  print(ax.get_xlim())
  print(ax.get_ylim())
  ax.set_ylim(100, 0)
  ax.set_xlim(0,100)
```

Comment: How do i add image in comment :)

Comment: Maybe, you can upload to the imgur and share the link?

Comment: Here is the link      https://imgur.com/DJKp1Y6    let me know of any improvements

Comment: Congratulation, this is definitely better than the previous one :)

Comment: Thanks,:) wonder what are those blank spaces in between?